# My pages disappeared from the list on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a serious problem.

Last weekend I moved some websites from an old server to other more powerfull. It's a new installation.

I'm using a AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 connected to a RDS MySQL.

In this new server the websites is working fine, but when I try to edit a page, noone appears on page list, as you can see on the image.

It's happening in all sites, including in a new site that I've installed right now.

Anybody knows what's going on?

Thanks a lot

Emanuel

[Image from screen>>](http://www.connix.com.br/images/lista.png)

***** I did a test and discovered that the problem is that I'm using a RDS MySQL instance instead of localhost. :(

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I've solved the problem.

There was a wrong parameter that cause an error on this specific select. The strange thing that just this select was affected.

I needed to increase sort_buffer_size and be careful with max_sort_length.

[]'s

Emanuel